# Ajax CalendarExtender

Tags: asp.net

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 RTMRel

I downloaded AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET40. Added them as reference.

when I added the textbox, extended with Calendar Extender which has final code as below:

WHen I press F5, i dont see anything happening when I click on textbox1. Please help... This is so simple and still not working for me.. :(

I've googled this for a while but none of the solution did help.. Please help! I've added assembly & ScriptManager but still not working

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
            Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1" Format="MMMM d, yyyy" >
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: I've added the script manager & also referred the assembly
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
             </asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: the format of your calendar is wrong,
try taking it this way Format="dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: PopupButtonID needed for the extender.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to a PopupButtonID and an ImageButton. So:

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1" Format="MMMM d, yyyy" PopupButtonID="ImageButton1" >
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="~/images/somegif.gif" />
```

Then click on the ImageButton to launch the CalendarExtender

Comment: Actually i didn't wanted to use Imagebutton & popup button. In this Ajax tool, we can just click on textbox, it will auto populate the calendar. I wonder why it didn't work. i used AJAX 2.0 dll and it worked for me... its definitely not because of the date format though as it worked for me in Ajax 2.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ScriptManager is right after your form tag

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Try using ToolkitScriptManager instead of ScriptManager

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```